# SSO: Authentication failed, reason - REMOTE_USER header can't be found in HTTP request

Tags: spring-security

We are using Oracle Access Manager for providing SSO for HP Service Request Catalog application.

Service request Catalog application requires userid as in form of REMOTE_USER header, this REMOTE_USER will be used for authentication.

So we are passing REMOTE_USER header with userid value from Oracle Access Manager.

Even after passing REMOTE_USER header, authentication is not successful. In the application logs we found error that "SSO: Authentication failed, reason - REMOTE_USER header can't be found in HTTP request".

Service Request Catalog application is using SPRING security 3.1.0 version.

Kindly let me know if we can change Service Request Catalog application to accept different headers other than REMOTE_USER for authentication.

Regards,
Gurivi

Answer (score 1):

Confirm that the server.xml file on Tomcat are set to get REMOTE_USER from the HTTP Header. To do this, follow these steps:
Locate # Define an AJP 1.3 Connector on port 8009 settings.
Verify that the property tomcatAuthentication is set to false.
[Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNz7z.jpg)